# Data provider format not working in amcharts

Tags: charts, amcharts

While setting the data to value field in am charts , if i need to set the value field like "value Field": "cities.a" its not working :( any help is appreciated

My data format:
data Provider": [ {"year": 2003,"cities":{"a": 2.0,"b": 2.5},"countries":{"c": 2.1,"d": 1.2} }, {"year": 2004,"cities":{"a": 2.6,"b": 2.7},"countries":{"c": 2.2,"d": 1.3} }]

Comment: I got a reply from Amcharts support as following: The above format isn't supported. The valueField only looks at the name of the property; it doesn't try to infer into any sub-objects if you put in a dot in the name. You need to flatten your object so that your values are directly accessible by the property name, e.g. {
    "year": 2004,
     "europe": 2.6,
     "namerica": 2.7
     "asia": 2.2,
     "lamerica": 1.3
}